# Align items in horizontal UIStackView from the center

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, uistackview

[image: here is what I have now]

Hi all :)
There is a situation when I need to align items in the UIStackView from the center. So if there is 2, 3, 4 (no matter how many) they should be aligned from the center, not from the left/right side etc.
Is it possible to implement?
I have parent **vertical** stackView and 2 nested **horizontal** stackviews with UIImageViews inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set parent UIStackView (vertical stackView) alignment to center.[image]